# Using a file to hold array items for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have create a Google Map using however, it has a lot of markers and it has become unwieldy to have them in the the same html file. To use the markers I first create a array as follows;

```
var markers = [

   ['Balham Leisure Centre',51.441234,-0.152297,'leisure_center.png'],
   ['Putney Leisure Centre',51.463955,-0.228771,'leisure_center.png'],
   ['Latchmere Leisure Centre',51.470967,-0.163805,'leisure_center.png']
]
```

then utilise them as follows;

```
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            icon: iconBase + markers[i][3],
        });

}
```

I would like to store the markers array in a separate text file like;

```
   ['Balham Leisure Centre',51.441234,-0.152297,'leisure_center.png'],
   ['Putney Leisure Centre',51.463955,-0.228771,'leisure_center.png'],
   ['Latchmere Leisure Centre',51.470967,-0.163805,'leisure_center.png']
```

then have the main page read that file and put it into the markers array so that everything still works the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't use any frameworks, in native JS you want to use XMLHttpRequest object. Save your data in a separate file (you might want to use JSON for example) and then follow the code below.

Basic usage:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(req.responseText);
    }
}
req.open('GET', url);
req.send();
```

Readmore: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest